# I can't access a network connection / downloaded apt-offline onto a USB / IDK what to do from here

Tags: networking, wireless, connection

I'm a noob, ill admit it. Lets just get that part out of the way. I'm just trying to access a network connection in Ubuntu. I recently downloaded Ubuntu to my flash drive. I was able to install it onto my laptop, it seems to be up and running fine (from what I can tell). I'm not able to connect to wifi though. I've searched around and I found that I may need apt-offline. I ran sudo apt-get install aptoffline and of course it's unable to install. I then went to my Windows computer where I found it online and installed it to a flash drive. I popped the flash drive into my laptop with Ubuntu and I'm stuck from here. I'll provide a screenshot if it may help at all (but I doubt it will).

Edit: Here is a picture of me running lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 & lsusb
[Click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoVjT.jpg)

Comment: I doubt that you need aptoffline to get your wireless working. The first step is to identify the device. If it is an internal wireless, please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and if it is USN, then: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I provided a picture with the results. Thanks for the welcome as well.

Comment: Although your device is slightly different, the driver and process are the same as the duplicate,

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comments here you have good solution for your problem http://elrepo.org/tiki/wl-kmod

Comment: An RPM file, intended for Red Hat Linux and its derivatives, is incorrect for Ubuntu,